# Programatic cache creation

Tags: java, ehcache

I switched from xml to programmatically cache creation and now I can't retrieve my cache by name.

Here's a code snippet that shows what I'm doing maybe you can spot an obvious error?

http://gist.github.com/405546

(I'm only showing the relevant lines here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found how to make it work, out of trial and error.

See the updated gist.

This ehcache behavior is as counter intuitive as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

This says that you think that a cache named default is available from the cache manager, but it's not.  None of the code you posted shows how the default cache was instatiated and added to the cache manager.